# How to Attach a logic to a page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to have a page in wordpress with some custom logic coming from a php file. How do i attach this php logic to a wordpress page.

Comment: What logic are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I search a little more and found that we can create template pages and they can have custom logic.

Comment: If you have an answer then you should accept it, even if you answered it yourself :)